# How can you put leaflet polylines in multiple panes?

Tags: leaflet

What am I doing wrong? The intent is to have a few (say 6) leafletjs panes, each containing many markers and polylines, so the panes can be hidden independently. [Here is a simplified program showing just two lines and markers in jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0shawrqx/15/). The problem is, the polylines all get grouped in the same SVG and all get hidden together. Each pane in the example should show one polyline and one marker.

I don't want to remove the polylines from the map to hide them, then recreating them would not perform well.

If needed, the polylines could be drawn using D3 on top of the leaflet map but I was hoping it could all be done in leaflet. 
Thanks!

JS:

```
    'use strict';

    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
    var map = L.map('map').setView([30.5, -0.09], 2); 
    L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
    }).addTo(map);

    var pane1 = map.createPane('pane1');
    var pane2 = map.createPane('pane2');
    function hide(pane) {
        pane.style.display = 'none';
    }
    function show(pane) {
        pane.style.display = '';
    }

    let icon = new L.Icon.Default();

    function dr(pane, latlng){
        L.polyline([[45.421, -75.697], latlng], {
            weight: 2,
            pane: pane
        }).addTo(map);

        L.marker(latlng, {
            icon: icon,
            pane: pane
        }).addTo(map);
    }

    // define two locations with lines from Ottawa
    dr(pane1, [ 42.3732216, -72.5198537 ]);
    dr(pane2, [ 35.9606384, -83.9207392 ]);

    function sleep(ms) {
        return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
    }
    async function loop(){
        for( var i = 0; i<100; i++){
            hide(pane1);
            show(pane2);
            await sleep(1000);

            hide(pane2);
            show(pane1);
            await sleep(1000);
        }
    }
    loop();});
```

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-xwE/Az9zrjBIphAcBb3F6JVqxf46+CDLwfLMHloNu6KEQCAWi6HcDUbeOfBIptF7tcCzusKFjFw2yuvEpDL9wQ==" crossorigin=""/>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.6.0/leaflet-src.js" integrity="sha256-wc8X54qvAHZGQY6nFv24TKlc3wtO0bgAfqj8AutTIu0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <style>
        html, body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
        }
        #map {
            width: 900px;
            height: 500px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id='map'></div>
</body>
</html>
<script src="c.js"></script>
```

Comment: "_recreating them would not perform well_" why do you think that would be the case? Have you tried it? Sounds like much less trouble than your current approach.

Comment: I tried it (in my app, not in the simplified test code posted here). Now the initial display is quick. I am displaying by year, and when the user clicks a control to advance a year the re-display has too much lag for my liking (hundreds of polylines get created).

Comment: Found a solution?